# Spyder debugger ignores breakpoints

Tags: debugging, spyder, breakpoints

I'm using `spyder 3.3.6` and, since a week ago or so, the debugger has suddenly start ignoring any breakpoints I define by placing a red dot with a double click on the corresponding line. Once I start debugging pressing Ctrl+5 the debugger stops at the first line of the code, even if there isn't a breakpoint. Then when I press Ctrl+12 to move to the next breakpoints the debugger just ignores them and terminates the process without showing any error message.

Have a look at the screenshot to get a better idea of the problem:
[image]

Any suggestion to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) That version is really old and it's not supported anymore. Please upgrade to our latest version (4.1.5 in Anaconda / 4.2.0 otherwise).

Comment: I have this problem too. Have you found any solution?

Comment: I did what Carlos Cordoba suggested. After upgrading to the latest version I no longer had the problem. @moha, maybe you should consider do the same.